# How to enable the Push Notification on Enterprise Network

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

> Problem:

Case i) I got an exception while running the below code connected with enterprise network running on virtual machine.

```
try
        {  PushNotificationChannel channel = null;
            channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
        }
```

> i.e Timeout error while requesting for the Channel URI for push notification.

Case ii) Tried to get the url/server address which might be blocked by the enterprise network while connecting with WNS  using fiddler but unfortunately was not successful.

***Note***: If I use open network the above code works as charm .

Looking for help, to fix the push notification issue on enterprise network. Also, if anyone knows how to get the WNS Server path/url which is being called when we requested for push channel uri.

Answer (score 0):

I have replied this issue in this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3392b097-b467-4773-bede-6ebfec24dc1a/enable-push-notifications-for-enterprise-application?forum=wpdevelop), you should make sure that your enterprise network do not have any policy which may block the following URLs. You can contact your network administrator to check the firewall settings.

1: The URL for Creating Channel URI: notify.windows.com

2: The URL for getting token:  https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sharing your valuable comments @Breeze Liu.

Comment: @vineetsahu you can try the suggestion and I am waiting for your update :).

Comment: Hi @BreezeLiu: I have communicated to my IT team for allowing these above URL into enterprise network. Also, I got some information on the below mentioned link which has a range of IP addresses which also need to be unblocked for WNS communication.[MSFT link for WNS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=44238)

Comment: @vineetsahu I suggest you to follow the [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3392b097-b467-4773-bede-6ebfec24dc1a/enable-push-notifications-for-enterprise-application?forum=wpdevelop) in the msdn, it has been moved to the corresponding forum, you will get support there.